# Translate default error messages in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, translate, loopback

My question is pretty simple, which is the best way to translate the default messages in loopback?

Example:

```
The `user` instance is not valid. Details: `email` Email already exists (value: "my@email.com").
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response to the question is: **you can't**.

Loopback give us some codes, about the error, and we have to handle and translate it on the front.

this link describes the errors in LB:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Error-object.html